# sql from vb cannot convert to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hi i'm trying to convert this line to get list of people active over todays date but cannot get it to work

```
adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand( _
            "select * from klijent where convert(varchar,convert(datetime,replace('" & DateTimeUgovora.Value.ToString & "','#','')),111) >= convert(varchar,getdate(),111)", myConn)
```

error is conversion of varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

my string that I get from front is

"29.11.2013. 19:41:08"[image: date problem]

I searched everywhere and cannot find the answer please help

Comment: If you are using SQL you dont need to do a CONVERT. Just put in the date like This `'25/12/2013'`

Comment: I have it in a string that says 29.11.2013. 19:41:08 and cannot put it in 29/11/2013 without converting it.I'm getting value from datetimepicker...

Comment: What field in kilijent is the date field you are comparing it to.

Comment: Kli_Ugovor_do is name of field in a table klijent, name of a datetimepicker is dateTimeUgovora which is value on a screen... oh my god Im idiot... iguess too tired after 14 hours of coding i need this kind of select  ... select * from klijent where convert(varchar,convert(datetime,KLI_UGOVOR_DO,111)) >= convert(varchar,getdate(),111);  but datetimepicker value instead getdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a quick console application with the string mention by you. This may be helpful.

```
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim myDateString As String = "29.11.2013. 19:41:08"
    myDateString = myDateString.Replace(".", "")
    Dim myDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myDateString, "ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString())
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

I created a quick module for tsql as well, maybe it will help:

```
Declare @dt varchar(20)
set @dt = '29.11.2013. 19:41:08'
select convert(datetime, Replace(@dt, '. ', ' '), 103)
```

Comment: Nice module but I thought tahat is possible somehow to convert this line into another string... I'm PL programmer so in PL this should be like select * from klijent where to_char(kli_ugovor_do,'mm.dd.yyyy') >= to_char(sysdate,'mm.dd.yyyy);   So i was aiming something like that... but cannot get it in sql tried everything but cannot figure out that string conversion into field shape that fits sql

Comment: Hey @Vedran, I updated the code. Maybe this will help. Thanks.

Comment: Thx ankit i think issue is in format... when I put my select like this it works in tsql...select * from klijent where kli_ugovor_do >= '2013-11-28 18:58:36';   but in VB i get value for string like "27.12.2013. 20:58:35"

Comment: @Vedran that is strange, can you post your vb.net code. I"ll try to replicate the issue on my end.

Comment: Solved it thanks for this convert that crossed my mind and i got solution.... adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand( _
            "select * from klijent where kli_ugovor_do >= convert(varchar(20),@dt,111)", myConn)      and @dt is datetimepicker.value

Comment: @VedranTurković Super

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to convert the datetime value to a string, because in SQL you can compare datetime values directly. This is much more stable as it doesn't depend on locale settings. I don't fully understand your SELECT clause as even if the comparison works, it will return either all the rows in the table or none. 
However, if you want to use the table column Kli_Ugovor_do in your comparison, you can change your statement to this:

```
adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand( _
            "select * from klijent where Kli_Ugovor_do >= getdate()", myConn)
```

Btw: in your statement you included the value of the combobox by string concatenation. You should get used to including parameters in your statements in order to avoid SQL injection attacks.

So if you want to use the value of the DateTimePicker, your code should look similar to this:

```
adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand( _
            "select * from klijent where Kli_Ugovor_do >= @dt", myConn)
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dateTimeUgovora.Value)
```

Comment: yes something like that i manage to get result with getdate but instead of getdate i need value from datetimepicker and that is my problem which I cannot solve... the one you wrote works but i have value in a datetimepicker that is selecting date which is greater or lower than date in my klijent table and that date is in datetimepicker and always results in a error no mather how i wrote it

Comment: @VedranTurković: I've updated my sample to use the DateTimePicker.

Comment: Thx Markus but I think this is issue with database and visual studio.... my results in databese when I hit select on field kli_ugovor_do are in this format 2013-11-28 18:58:36 and from datetimepicker when I pass it to variable i get "27.12.2013. 20:58:35"

Comment: @VedranTurković: What you see is a string representation of the values so that you can read them. Internally, both the db and .NET store datetime values as some form of number. This makes comparing dates much easier than if they'd store it as a string that differs from culture to culture. Therefore, the result of the select and what you see in the debugger might be in a different format, but if you use a statement similar to the second one, this won't matter and the comparison will be valid.